# Appending html string in handlebars template in backboneJS is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, handlebars.js

calline renderBankInvContainers function doesn't appending html(field String) in html page.

```
var editAccountView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName : 'div',
    className : 'edit-account-wrap',

    initialize : function() {
        var self = this;
        this.$el.append(editAccountTmpl());
        $('.application-content-wrap').append(this.$el);
        this.collection = new itemFormDataSummaryCollection();
        this.collection.fetch({
            timeout : 30000,
            type : 'POST',                  
            success : function(response) {                      
                var result = response.toJSON();
                if (result[0].containerType == 'BANK' || result[0].containerType == 'STOCKS') {
                    self.renderBankInvContainers();
                }
                self.$el.find('.edit-account-wrap ').html(editAccountContentTmpl());
            }
        });
    },

    renderBankInvContainers : function() {
        var field;
        field = this.displayField("Nickname", itemFormData['nickname'], "text", "nickname", false);
        $('.edit-account-wrap').find('.input-row').append(field);
        field = this.displayField("Include in Net Worth", itemFormData['includeInNetworth'], "toggle", "includeInNetworth", false);
        $('.edit-account-wrap').find('.input-row').append(field);
    },

    displayField : function(dispLabel, dispData, dispComp, name, readOnly) {
        var finalDispalyField;
        if (dispComp == "text") {
            var label = '<div class="small-6 columns"><label>' + dispLabel + '</label></div>';
            var input;
            if (readOnly) {
                input = '<div class="small-6 columns"><input type="text" name"' + name + '" value="' + dispData + '" readonly></div>';
            } else {
                input = '<div class="small-6 columns"><input type="text" name"' + name + '" value="' + dispData + '"></div>';
            }
            finalDispalyField = label + input;
            return finalDispalyField;
        }
        if (dispComp == "toggle") {
            var label = '<div class="small-6 columns"><label>' + dispLabel + '</label></div>';
            var input = '<div class="small-6 columns"><div class="switch small round"><input id="z" name="' + name + '" type="radio" checked><input id="z" name="' + name + '" type="radio"></div></div>';
            finalDispalyField = label + input;
            return finalDispalyField;
        }
    }
});     

return editAccountView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your itemFormData in the `renderBankInvContainers` function is not set.

Try in the fetch success callback to set the view collection, like this :

```
success : function(response) {
    self.collection = response;
    var result = response.toJSON();
    if (result[0].containerType == 'BANK' || result[0].containerType == 'STOCKS') {
        self.renderBankInvContainers();
    }
    self.$el.find('.edit-account-wrap ').html(editAccountContentTmpl());
}
```

and in your `renderBankInvContainers` function you can use `this.collection`.

I think that you have to change the if statement in this function.

Answer (score 0):

there was error because i was loading template after append() method. before calling renderBankInvcontainers() i need to call below statement.
self.$el.find('.edit-account-wrap ').html(editAccountContentTmpl());

```
success : function(response) {
    self.collection = response;
    var result = response.toJSON();
    **self.$el.find('.edit-account-wrap ').html(editAccountContentTmpl());**
    if (result[0].containerType == 'BANK' || result[0].containerType == 'STOCKS') {
        self.renderBankInvContainers();
    }    
}
```